# Keep File as Socket and wait until the end of writing from another process

Tags: php, file-io

Let's say that we have a **program X that continuously write a file** for example the /tmp/test.file

I have a script in PHP that serves this file to the client so that he can download/read it.

***How i'm able to do this continuously as the data are being written in the /tmp/test.file?***

If i use the below code

```
<?php

$fp = fopen("/tmp/test.file","r");
while(!feof($fp))
{
 echo fread($fp,4096);
}
fclose($fp);
```

It instantly stops because it reads the whole file until EOF so it doesnt care if another process is writing at this file.

Thank you

Comment: Even if you are iterating on file chunks, that's still a synchronous file read. Why do you need to write to a file? Try writing to a stream, and deliver the stream itself to the browser with stream_get_contents. However, keep in mind that PHP's lifecycle (the fact that everything happens on a single request) might mean it isn't the best tool to do some specific tasks, like for instance streaming radio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a suggestion, use a continues Ajax call (for example 5 seconds interval) to the `PHP` script file, and get the file content via offset. You can store the current offset of file into `SESSION` or `COOKIE`.

You can get file offset by using `PHP`'s [ftell](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php) function.

As `PHP`'s official document defines `ftell()`:

> **ftell — Returns the current position of the file read/write pointer**

Also, [stream_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php) function might be useful as `PHP`'s official document defines it:

> **stream_get_contents — Reads remainder of a stream into a string**

then, In each interval, append the response data to a HTML tag.